# Remove Image/Symbol from Highchart Graph

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am dynamically adding images to the graph, something like below:

```
marker[group] = chart.renderer.g('icons').attr({zIndex: this_z}).add();

symbol[group] = chart.renderer.image(marker_url, -50, 0, 20, 37).add(marker[group]);
```

How do I remove a image/symbol from the graph? Something like .remove?

Comment: have not been able to find anything around that in highcharts docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is possible. Any renderer function like `arc` or `g` returns element. Every element contains `element` field of `Element` type. With jQuery you can do everything with this element, for example:

```
marker[group] = chart.renderer.g('icons').attr({zIndex: this_z});
marker[group].add();
$(marker[group].element).remove();
```

This will do the trick.